How to Modify Word footer image in openXml
I have a template document where the footer of the first page uses an image for the full display, but now I need to modify the image so that the contents of the image are aligned with the contents of the document. After my modification, all the header content starting from the next page can no longer be displayed through the code setting content as originally.Can anyone tell me how to modify the footer image of the template document so that my header can be displayed correctly with the content set by the code?

Align the footer image on the first page using the document editor and ensure the "Different First Page" option is enabled for headers and footers. Then, verify that your code correctly applies headers to subsequent pages.

The "Different First Page" option is enabled for headers and footers. My footer image is already there, but as soon as I adjust the image, the content of the header using the code will not be displayed.

It's hard to say from here. I would recommend using word to make equivalent changes, then a 3 way compare between the before and after versions. That might help reveal what is different.
